# Matplotlib - 10 x 10 matrix only populating last instance

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot 100 random images from the notMNIST dataset in a 10x10 matrix, however only the last subplot is returning an image. Image data is stored in x, and labels in y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

num_subplots = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=num_subplots, ncols=num_subplots, figsize=(10, 6))
for idx in range(10): 
    n = np.random.randint(np.sum(y < 0), len(y))
    imgl = x[n,:].reshape((28,28))
    imshow(imgl, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is x? (short comment)

Comment: x is numpy array storing number of samples, width, and height of each image.

Comment: Change your `for` statement to `for idx, a in enumerate(ax.ravel()):` and then call `imshow` on the `Axes` instance where you want the image to occur, i.e. `a.imshow(img1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray')`.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked perfectly! Thanks Thomas.

Comment: @oniera Great, I formulated it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `plt.imshow()`, the plot will always appear at the currently active subplot which, in your case, is the last subplot that has been created. Instead, you can loop over all subplots and call `imshow()` on the subplots themselves using the object oriented matplotlib syntax. As you generate an array of subplots, the `subplots()` function returns a 2d `numpy` array, wich you first need to convert into a 1D iterable, which you can achieve with the `ravel()` function. See the below code for a complete example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline

num_subplots = 10
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_subplots, ncols=num_subplots, figsize=(10, 6))
for idx,ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()): 
    n = np.random.randint(np.sum(y < 0), len(y))
    imgl = x[n,:].reshape((28,28))
    ax.imshow(imgl, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

Note that I renamed the original `ax` to `axes` to make it more apparent that you have many subplots (Axes instances). Note also that, if you want more control, you could loop over the rows and columns of your subplot arrangement separately. In this case you would use two `for` loops and access your subplots using `axes[row,col]`, something like this:

```
for row in range(num_subplots):
   for col in range(num_subplots):
      #some code here
      axes[row,col].imshow(...)
```

Hope this helps.